# Django - using modern middlewares, should I ever use process_view?

Tags: django, django-middleware, django-3.1

I'm migrating a few middlewares to a new Django codebase, using Django 3.1.
I'm obviously using `MIDDLEWARE` and not `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

I see that `process_view` is still supported. But I don't understand why would I ever use that. Does it add anything over using a standard Middleware using `get_response` directly?

When will this `process_view` even be called in this flow?

Comment: Are you saying the `process_view(...)` method is getting called in Django 3.1?

Comment: Actually haven't tested. Just trying to figure what is the correct way to write a new Middleware, should I use that, and what functionality does it add

Comment: *"... what is the correct way to write a new Middleware"..."* isn't it well documented here, [Writing your own middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/) ?